# Mysql order by very slow，Non-driven table fields sorted （or Cross-table queries）without using indexes

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

## I. Phenomenon and background of the problem

**Problems encountered**:

- Mysql order by very slow，Non-driven table fields sorted without using indexes
- a.CreatedAt query is very fast(119ms Get); f.Type query is very slow(12.194s Get)

**Phenomenon：** In MySQL, the left join (view) query is performed on multiple tables, and the Order By FIELD () function is used to perform the specified sorting. It is found that the index is not used, resulting in slow query speed

**Demand background**: it is arranged in reverse or positive order according to the creation time, and the request for approval is placed at the bottom by default

```sql
-- Query view: vi_orderinfo

EXPLAIN
SELECT
  *
FROM
  vi_orderinfo b
WHERE
  1= 1 and b.Status!= 5
ORDER BY
  FIELD(b.Type,0,4,1,2,3),
  b.CreatedAt DESC;
```

## II. Related Definitions:

`f`Table Type field is indexed: NON-Type

`f`table is related to `a` table (driver table): a JOIN f ON f.OrderId = a.Id

I need to specify the sort, Type=1,2,3 The query result set should be displayed at the end

### current version of the MySQL database

```sql
SELECT VERSION() vi_orderinfo 

-- Output：
vi_worderinfo|  
-------------+  
8.0.18       |
```

### Cross-table queries

The index disappears when you query across tables

```sql
-- Query the relationship between table a and table f in view: vi_orderinfo

EXPLAIN   
SELECT
*
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    `a`.*,
    `f`.`Type` AS `Type`
  FROM
    `tb_orderinfo` `a`
  left JOIN 
    `tb_status` `f` ON  `f`.`OrderId` = `a`.`Id`   AND `f`.`Deleted` = 0
  WHERE
    `a`.`Deleted` = 0  AND `a`.`ServiceProviderCode` IS NULL 
)vw
WHERE
  1 = 1  AND vw.WorkStatus != 10
ORDER BY 
  FIELD(vw.TypeStatus, 0, 4, 1, 2, 3) ,
  vw.InstallTime DESC;
 

--  Output

id|select_type|table|partitions|type|possible_keys  |key            |key_len|ref                    |rows |filtered|Extra      |
--+-----------+-----+----------+----+---------------+---------------+-------+-----------------------+-----+--------+-----------+
 1|SIMPLE     |a    |          |ALL |               |               |       |                       |53129|   100.0|           |
 1|SIMPLE     |f    |          |ref |NON-OrderId|NON-OrderId|37     |serviceordercenter.a.Id|    1|   100.0|Using where|
```

## III. My solution ideas and tried methods

**CASE WHEN**: The query is also very slow, and the index is not used

```sql
-- Query view: vi_orderinfo

SELECT *,
       case when b.Type in (1,2,3) then 1 else 0 END AS RequestReviewType
FROM vi_orderinfo b
WHERE 1=1
  and b.Status != five
ORDER BY
RequestReviewType ASC，CreatedAt desc
```

**FIELD ():** The second one is changed to the Demo of the above aspect, and the function FIELD () is used for sorting

**Jian:** At first, it was left jion. Later, it was changed to jion. The size of the result set was a problem. Like jion, inner jion wrote jion

**STRAIGHT_JOIN:** This view is used for multiple interfaces, and the driver table a is heavily used elsewhere and cannot affect the ordering of other modules

**Redundant fields, temporary tables, and virtual columns do not seem to work**

## 4、 What I want to achieve

How to solve the problem of slow query time? I use paging query to request more than 10 seconds, which is too long!

My brain has stopped, please help me TVT

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions and your index definitions, as well the output of EXPLAIN. Showing  some sample data and a sample result will also help. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: The question seems to be 'why isn't myql using an index with my view?' - is that correct? There are some awkward translations in the question (not sure what a 'drive table' is). To get some help please edit the question to indicate the version of mysql you're using, the view definition, the relevant schema - and replace the image of the explain output with the text equivalent. https://www.db-fiddle.com/ or similar is also helpful for DB problems :).

Comment: [Edit]ing your question to tell us the exact version (the output of `SELECT VERSION()`) of your DBMS will help us too. Newer versions have [functional indexes](https://www.percona.com/blog/mysql-8-0-functional-indexes/).

Comment: Please don't use the same alias (`b`) for two different tables.  I am confused; the parser may also be confused.

Answer (score 0):

This *may* help:

```
SELECT  a2.*
    FROM  (
        SELECT  a1.*
            FROM  `tb_orderinfo` `a1`
            WHERE  a1.Status!= 5
              AND  `a1`.`Deleted` = 0
              AND  `a1`.`ProviderCode` IS NULL 
          ) AS a2
    LEFT JOIN  `tb_order` `b`  ON `b`.`OrderId` = `a2`.`Id` AND  `b`.`Deleted` = 0
    LEFT JOIN  `tb_app` `c`    ON `c`.`OrderId` = `a2`.`Id` AND  `c`.`Deleted` = 0
    LEFT JOIN  `tb_cust` `d`   ON `d`.`OrderId` = `a2`.`Id` AND  `d`.`Deleted` = 0
    LEFT JOIN  `tb_remarksinfo` `e`
                               ON `e`.`OrderId` = `a2`.`Id` AND  `e`.`Deleted` = 0
    JOIN  `tb_status` `f` 
                               ON `f`.`OrderId` = `a2`.`Id` AND  `f`.`Deleted` = 0
    ORDER BY  FIELD(a2.`Type`,0,4,1,2,3) , a2.CreatedAt DESC
```

With indexes

```
a1:  INDEX(Deleted, ProviderCode, Status)
b:  INDEX(OrderId,  Deleted)
c:  INDEX(OrderId,  Deleted)
d:  INDEX(OrderId,  Deleted)
e:  INDEX(OrderId,  Deleted)
f:  INDEX(OrderId,  Deleted)
```

But what would really speed it up is to get rid of the `LEFT JOINs` since you are not using those tables for anything!  The Optimizer is probably too dumb to toss them for you.

Note:  If there is also a `LIMIT`, we need to duplicate the `ORDER BY` inside the derived table and put the `LIMIT` only there.

As for `FIELD()` not using an index -- No function will allow an index to be used.  See:  [*sargable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)